# Can't read cookie value, always getting null

Tags: c#, asp.net

Actually my problem is that I'm not able to read a cookie value. It always shows `null`. My cookie name is *intUserId*

My C# Code is listed below

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("intUserId");
myCookie = Request.Cookies["intUserId"];
```

I have to read a content value of *52*. I'm struggling with this issue. 
The cookie information should be `name = intUserId` and `content = 52`

Comment: just have a look Henk Holterman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the cookie you have to return it to the client. Use:

```
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Comment: just have a look on screenshot

Comment: Check that hostname matches between pages that write and read. Path also has to match or be root (as in your case). Use Fiddler to see what's leaving the browser.

Comment: Well, your code sample is a bit untraditional? I don't hope It's the full code. I would myself; get the cookie, check if It's null, if yes, set the new value or deny access, if no, grant access. I wouldn't create a cookie and then read it immediately after that. And since I don't know the flow of the site, I can't give you a more correct answer

Comment: Cookie is writing in client application. they gave me only the cookie name and URL. If user hits the URL the cookie will create.

Comment: @sathishkumar - cookies are not normally set by clients. That makes this a very incomplete question.

Comment: can we read a cookie written in different host. Cookie sets in "cms01-dev" and gets in "localhost"